# How to set a text to Jqgrid dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I want to set a default value to jqgrid dropdown when click the add new button. My Jqgrid code is following.

```
jQuery("#grdDrawdownSchedule").jqGrid({
        url: RootUrl + 'ECB/DDSGridData',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'POST',
        height: 130,
        colNames: ['id', 'Drawdown Date', 'Currency', 'Amount'],
        colModel: [
                    { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 30, sorttype: "int", editable: false, hidden: true },
                    { name: 'DdDate', index: 'DdDate', width: 130, align: 'left', editable: true,
                        editoptions: {
                            readonly: 'readonly',
                            size: 10, maxlengh: 10,
                            dataInit: function (element) {
                                $(element).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy', changeMonth: true,
                                    changeYear: true, constrainInput: false, showOn: 'both',
                                    buttonImage: RootUrl + 'Content/Images/grid_Calendar.png',
                                    buttonText: 'Show Calendar',
                                    buttonImageOnly: true
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    { name: 'CurrencyName', index: 'CurrencyName', width: 120, editable: true, edittype: "select" },
                    { name: 'Amount', index: 'Amount', align: "right", width: 120, editable: true,
                        editoptions: { size: "20", maxlength: "16", dataInit: function (element) {
                            $(element).keypress(function (e) {
                                $('#AvgMaturityLoan').val("0");
                                if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && e.which != 46 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
                                    return false;
                                }
                                var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
                                if (charCode == 46 && this.value.split('.').length > 1)
                                    return false;
                            });
                        }
                        }
                    },
        //{ name: 'tadte', index: 'tdate', width: 130, "editable": true, "sorttype": "date", editrules: { "date": true }, "editoptions": { "dataInit": "initDateEdit"} },                                               
                 ],
        loadComplete: function () {

            $("#grdDrawdownSchedule").setColProp('CurrencyName', { editoptions: { value: JSON.parse(Currencies)} });


        },
        cellEdit: true,
        rowNum: 100,
        rownumbers: true,
        cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
        caption: "Drawdown Schedule",
        multiselect: true,
        shrinkToFit: false, forceFit: true,
        width: 490,
        postData: {
            "lrnid": "0",
            "data": ""
        }

    });
```

And my Add New button for the grid

```
 $("#btnAddNewDrawdownSche").click(function () {
        if (ValidateRow($("#grdDrawdownSchedule"))) {
            var idAddRow = $("#grdDrawdownSchedule").getGridParam("reccount")
            emptyItem = [{ id: idAddRow + 1, DrawdownDate: "", Currency: "", amount: ""}];
            jQuery("#grdDrawdownSchedule").jqGrid('addRowData', 0, emptyItem);
            $("#grdDrawdownSchedule").jqGrid('setCell', rowId, 'CurrencyName', selectedLoanCurrencyValue);
        }
    });
```

When I click the Add New button, Then initially I want to set the 'INR' value to the CurrencyName dropdown column. So how to set the default value to the Jqgrid's column.

Comment: No, I did not try, but i am new to jqgrid so can you please help how to use the selectoption(index,true)

Comment: Does this work pls check and let us know`$("#grdDrawdownSchedule").setColProp(CurrencyName, { editoptions: { value: <value>} }) ` value should be in `1:INR` format ,i is id and INR value.modify accordingly and check

Comment: Yes, this is working, but i want to load dynamic values, In which the INR value should come to first that's mean when i click the add new button then the value should auto populate. And the value is loaded from a variable named currencies.

Comment: Ok.somehow you would have to reshuffle that array and set that.so this needs to be set `var currencies= { '1': 'INR', '2': 'USD' };` like that so INR being first element would be default selected

Comment: I don't want to INR being first element, I want to auto populate it. If i want to change the currency, then only we should change.   Note: Until we choose a currency the column is empty. So I need to auto populate to before edit or click the dropdown.

Comment: ok try to add `defaultValue: 'INR'` this way `$("#grdDrawdownSchedule").setColProp(CurrencyName, { editoptions: { value: <value>,defaultValue: 'INR'}})`

Comment: I tried this too, But it is not working. Is there any way to select the currency by Id?. I have the INR currency id, So any possible to get value by id from the currencies variable. Note the currencies variable contains the values like     1:INR,2:USD,3:GBP  etc

Comment: you can split by , then split by : then get first splitted value where second splitted value =INR